# How to set the video playback rate or perform a seek() using gst-launch?

Tags: command-line, video, media-player, subtitles, gstreamer

**Is it possible to change the playback rate of a video in `gst-launch` to make it play faster/slower? Or is there a way to set the video to start playing from a specific position?**

Take into consideration the following pipeline that I'm using to play both audio/video with subtitle:

```
gst-launch filesrc location=tbbt_s05e01.srt ! subparse ! bot. filesrc location=tbbt_s05e01.avi ! decodebin name=decoder decoder. ! queue ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink decoder. ! timeoverlay ! textoverlay name=bot valignment=bottom ! xvimagesink
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And the answer was found using a gstreamer plugin named [gnonlin](http://gnonlin.sourceforge.net/). This component includes several gstreamer elements including `gnlfilesource` which can start the video at a specific position.

The following command loads a video file and a subtitle and starts playing at the position specified in `media-start` (nanoseconds):

```
gst-launch filesrc location=/data/videos/tbbt_s05e01.srt ! subparse ! bot. gnlfilesource location=file:///data/videos/tbbt_s05e01.avi duration=10000000000000 media-start=100000000000 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! textoverlay name=bot valignment=bottom  ! xvimagesink
```